# I need help to sort the array using property in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have this array I want to sort this using the property ( compositeUsersAvailableCount )

can anyone help me to sort this?

I am using this function currently but it would not help me.

```
let dynamicSort =   function (property) {

           console.log(typeof(property));
            
            var sortOrder = 1;
            return function (a,b) {
                // var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
                var result = a[property] - b[property];
                return result * sortOrder;
            }
        }


[
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '09:30',
    compositeEndTime: '10:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '09:45',
    compositeEndTime: '10:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:00',
    compositeEndTime: '11:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:15',
    compositeEndTime: '11:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:30',
    compositeEndTime: '11:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '12:30',
    compositeEndTime: '13:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '12:45',
    compositeEndTime: '13:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:00',
    compositeEndTime: '14:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:15',
    compositeEndTime: '14:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:30',
    compositeEndTime: '14:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '17:30',
    compositeEndTime: '18:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '17:45',
    compositeEndTime: '18:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:00',
    compositeEndTime: '19:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:15',
    compositeEndTime: '19:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:30',
    compositeEndTime: '19:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '19:30',
    compositeEndTime: '20:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '19:45',
    compositeEndTime: '20:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:00',
    compositeEndTime: '21:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:15',
    compositeEndTime: '21:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:30',
    compositeEndTime: '21:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '21:30',
    compositeEndTime: '22:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '21:45',
    compositeEndTime: '22:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:00',
    compositeEndTime: '23:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:15',
    compositeEndTime: '23:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:30',
    compositeEndTime: '23:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  }
]
12
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Asia/Calcutta
Server Running At: localhost:8080
Example app listening on port 3000!
[Object: null prototype] {
  users_id: '8,10,11',
  userid: '8',
  startdate: '2020-08-010',
  enddate: '2020-08-010',
  starttime: '00:00',
  endtime: '24:00',
  event_duration: '60',
  weekday: '1',
  weekend: '1',
  advance_search: '1'
}
hello2
25
[
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '09:30',
    compositeEndTime: '10:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '09:45',
    compositeEndTime: '10:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:00',
    compositeEndTime: '11:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:15',
    compositeEndTime: '11:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '10:30',
    compositeEndTime: '11:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '12:30',
    compositeEndTime: '13:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '12:45',
    compositeEndTime: '13:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:00',
    compositeEndTime: '14:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:15',
    compositeEndTime: '14:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '13:30',
    compositeEndTime: '14:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '17:30',
    compositeEndTime: '18:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '17:45',
    compositeEndTime: '18:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:00',
    compositeEndTime: '19:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:15',
    compositeEndTime: '19:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '18:30',
    compositeEndTime: '19:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '19:30',
    compositeEndTime: '20:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '19:45',
    compositeEndTime: '20:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:00',
    compositeEndTime: '21:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:15',
    compositeEndTime: '21:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '20:30',
    compositeEndTime: '21:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '21:30',
    compositeEndTime: '22:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '21:45',
    compositeEndTime: '22:45',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:00',
    compositeEndTime: '23:00',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 12,
    isBestCaseScenario: true
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:15',
    compositeEndTime: '23:15',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 9,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  },
  {
    compositeDate: '2020-08-10',
    compositeIsWeekDay: true,
    compositeStartTime: '22:30',
    compositeEndTime: '23:30',
    compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6,
    isBestCaseScenario: false
  }
]
```

Comment: "it would not help me" is not a problem description. What happens? Why is that wrong?

Comment: what description you want regarding this, as i just want to sort this array its a simple description

Comment: @underscore_d  the function that I am using will not produce the correct results

Comment: You don't show how the function is called. You don't clearly state what of that wall of text is the input, what is the current output, and what is the desired output.

Comment: @underscore_d  if you can see this property  compositeUsersAvailableCount: 6 in the array it show the array in the order 6,12,9,12, 6, 12,9 but I want result like this  6,6,6,9,9,9,12 and so on

Answer (score 1):

pass your property array here

```
let dynamicSort  = function(item) {
        return item.sort((a,b) => a.compositeUsersAvailableCount > b.compositeUsersAvailableCount? 1: -1)
}
console.log(dynamicSort(property));
```

Comment: indraraj ,  why sort function is not working properly in live server it works perfectly in local server

Comment: can you show me whole function btw are you using mongoose if yes it is so easy to sort without having extra code . await Model.find({}).sort({ compositeUsersAvailableCount:1}).exec()

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: this may help you https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/

Comment: issue resolved, error due to wrong logic in the function code.